# Is WEBP output possible on Google App Engine with PHP72 and ImageMagick?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, imagemagick, webp

I have a PHP72 app on Google App Engine using ImageMagick to output image resizes.

I added `$im->setImageFormat('webp');` and, though it worked fine locally, when deployed to App Engine it generates an "Unable to set image format" error.

I've checked `phpinfo()` on App Engine and can confirm that their PHP 7.2.23 runtime, with `extension=imagick.so` enabled, does not include WEBP support. I've also tried the php73 runtime and it does not support it either.

Is it possible to configure App Engine's ImageMagick to include WEBP support?

Comment: ImageMagick would need to be (re-)compiled with the webp delegate. See https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

Comment: This question is specifically regarding App Engine, so I cannot compile ImageMagick myself. I've since raised an issue with Google and they've recommend using Cloud Run if I need WebP support. It's pretty incredible that App Engine doesn't support WebP by default; a file format created in 2010 and developed by Google itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think much can be done here with standard PHP environment.

The real workaround is using Cloud Run if you are not using some specific features not yet implemented there.
Another thing that might work is [switching to flexible with custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build) and using your own image with preconfigured ImageMagick.